# Want to how could i i place my image weather i want

Tags: php, image, image-uploading

I want to make my text editor completely functional like i want to place my image through CMS weather i want like after the paragraph or any where i want.

```
<?php
include('includes/db.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $post_title = $_POST['title'];
    $post_date = date('d-m-y');
    $post_author = $_POST['author'];
    $post_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $post_content = $_POST['content'];
    $post_book = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if ($post_title == '' || $post_author == '' || $post_keywords == '' || $post_content == '') {
        echo "<script>alert('Anyone field is empty')</script>";

        exit();
    } else {

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_image, "../e-books/$post_book");


        $insert_query = "insert into post (p_title,p_date,p_author,p_image,p_keywords,p_content) values ('$post_title','$post_date','$post_author','$post_book','$post_keywords','$post_content')";

        if (mysql_query($insert_query)) {

            echo "<script>window.open('insert_post.php?posted=Post is going to be published....!!!','_self')</script>";

            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: People would be much more inclined to help you if you bothered using the Preview before posting...

Answer (score 0):

You can use richtext editors and  integrate with upload file to remote server features.

for example integrated version of [**`CKEditor`**](http://ckeditor.com/demo) & [**`CKFinder`**](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide) Or [**`Tinymce`**](http://www.tinymce.com/)